# Databse failed to load in couchDB(error : "nodedown" reason : "progress not possible")

Tags: couchdb

While creating database in couchDB it shows
**This database failed to load.**

Not able to find any reason.

My couchDb is single node cluster DB

[image]

Comment: Can u elaborate a little more: OS, steps taken, CouchDB version, install location etc. too many unknown to give advice

Comment: DO you have write access to the storage area?

Comment: Yes I Do have access to storage area. Current version is v. 3.2.2. Windows 10 server . 
installed on D:/Apache. Step it was working before suddenly for newly created project it started showing "This data Failed to load"